# Beta Decay - Doesn't Add Up

Tags: physical-chemistry, nuclear

The definition of [beta $(\beta^-)$ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) is that an electron is produced.

For example,

$$\ce{^131_53I -> ^131_54Xe + e^-}$$

So **iodine** forms **Xe** and releases **one electron with a -1 charge only and no weight**.

My question is that if an electron is released, then there is still a proton left so shouldn't it still be iodine? Then you should gain an extra proton. I personally feel like something is missing here, Also about Positron Emission or Positron Decay.

Anyone know why or what?

---

Edit: The "duplicate" question picked by many does not fully answer the question as well as bon did here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a physics question but I will answer it anyway.
I'm not sure how much subatomic physics you know so I will give two different versions.
Simply put, a neutron decays to form a proton and electron.
$$\ce{n ->  p+ + e-}$$
This explains why the proton number increases by one to form Xenon.

More properly a down quark inside a neutron decays to form an up quark, an electron and an electron antineutrino as a result of weak nuclear force interactions.
$$\ce{d -> u + e- + \overline{\nu}_{e}}$$

This causes the neutron ($\ce{udd}$) to turn into a proton ($\ce{uud}$) leading to the increase in atomic number.

This type of beta decay is know as $\beta^{-}$ decay. There is also $\beta^{+}$ decay which is a similar process where a proton becomes a neutron, positron and an electron neutrino:
$$\ce{^23_12Mg -> ^23_11Na + e+ + \nu_{e}}$$
$$\ce{u -> d + e+ + \nu_{e}}$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay $%edit$

Comment: I'll just stick with the textbook and not ask any questions. Haha. Don't have time to comprehend when exam is in a couple of days.

Comment: Unless you have a particular need or desire to understand particle physics the first equation should allow you to work out whats going on

Comment: Then why do they write the electron after the arrow, isn't it just with the Xe. I don't see the need to write the electron. Just say that Xe forms.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the $\ce{B^+}$decay. Like you explained with $\ce{B^-}$.

Comment: The electrons are ejected from the nucleus at very high energies, and therefore velocities, and so are not captured by the atom. This is why we usually write them seperately.

Comment: What is the e in the Positron Emission? Shouldn't that be just a regular -e.

Comment: $e^{+}$ is a positron which is the antiparticle of an electron. It has to be $e^{+}$ not $e^{-}$ in order to conserve charge

Comment: But when a proton becomes a neutron, what about the electron that is associated with that proton? So shouldn't the electron get ejected if a proton turns to a neutron?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20153/discussion-between-bon-and-awesomeflame123).

Comment: when writing nuclear decay equations we are only interested in nuclei and the decay products. the electron in an orbital that i think you are referring to remains there. 
the positron (and the electron in beta minus decay) comes from the nucleus and has nothing to do with the electrons in orbitals around the atom.

Answer (score 3):

When we talk about an unstable atom that will decay by emitting $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\gamma$ radiation, the nucleus is the thing that's unstable, right?

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_particle) puts it,

> An unstable atomic nucleus with an excess of neutrons may undergo β− decay, where a neutron is converted into a proton, an electron and an electron antineutrino (the antiparticle of the neutrino)

You can forget the anti-matter part. Just remember than in $\beta$ decay there is a neutron from the nucleus that is being "devolved" into eminently a proton and an electron. The electron leaves the atom with high velocity and energy, but the proton remains. So, for each atom that a $\beta$ particle is released from, we have:

$$\ce{^A_zM -> ^A_{z+1}M+}$$

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a neutron is converted to a proton, releasing an electron in the form of beta radiation. That is why the mass stays constant but the number of protons increases by 1.

Comment: I don't quite understand that, any clarification please.